# Is exports an object returned from module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have this hello.js file:

```
var greeting = function() {
    console.log('Hello');
}

module.exports = greeting;
```

Then in main.js:

```
var temp = require('./hello.js');
temp();
```

When you say `module.exports = greeting` is that attaching the greeting function to the exports object on module. Since when I require `hello.js` in `main.js` I am able to call temp() directly. And don't have to do like temp.greeting();

Does this mean that since `require` `returns module.exports` it just returning the method on the exports object rather than returning the exports object entirely correct? I am confused on why it is returning what is on the exports object (the greeting function) and not the real exports object itself.

Comment: On that last line in hello.js, you set the "exports" property of the `module` object to `greeting`. There no longer is an "exports object" anywhere in scope. I think you're mixing up the module object and the original exports object.

Comment: Hi, sorry for getting back to you late! Thank you for clearing it up! I understand it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require(...)` returns `module.exports` from that module. This is usually an object, but it can also be anything else (usually a function) like in your case where the module exports only a single function.

There's nothing wrong with doing this - `module.exports` is just a plain object (there's most likely something like `module.exports = {};` somewhere in the code that runs "around" the contents of a module's js file)

Comment: H! Sorry for getting back to you late. So basically when you do module.exports = greeting, exports is not an object anymore but it is really a function like the other poster said.